# Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: “Too many connections”? - Multithreading

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have a problem that my application runs almost like 300-400 threads at any time. So there are some problem i am having with connection to mysql database which throws exception at any time that "Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: “Too many connections”? ".
And i checked and make sure of closed all connections in the right way which i have connection to db.

For handling this approach i wrote a method but i am not sure if this is the right way to do it. This method has been used for all threads to get database connection.
Should i change the method or should i add synchronized to this, i am not sure what to do about this exception

```
    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection(){
    try{
        return  (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306xxx?useUnicode=true"
                + "&characterEncoding=utf-8", "root", "xxx");
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Util.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));// Equals = Thread.sleep(...);
        return getDatabaseConnection();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use a connection pool. The error comes your database anyway, so check your MySQL configuration.

Comment: You are also probably leaking connections somewhere. Check that every connection is closed in a `finally` block or a try-with-resources statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a db connection for each thread. Better way to handle this is creating a connection pool or a singleton class to reach db. I found an old page to achieve this : http://rdeshapriya.com/a-singleton-java-class-for-mysql-db-connection/

Comment: Should i never close connection ? Is this approach occurs another problems such as leaking or etc.?

Comment: Of course you should close the connection, but you can close it when you shutdown the application. It depends on your application but if you have an application with 300 reqs per sec its better to have one connection available all the time. It's better than closing and creating db connections, which is a little bit more time and resource consuming.